# Pattern matching for a string starting with character and ending with digit

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a valid string that always start with fixed string `SOME_START_FORMAT_` then end with one or more digits. So valid strings are

```
SOME_START_FORMAT_1234
SOME_START_FORMAT_12
```

Invalid strings are

```
SOME_INVALID_FORMAT_1234
SOME_START_FORMAT_
SOME_START_FORMAT_1234_
SOME_START_FORMAT_1234_MORE
```

I am trying with this regex `^SOME_START_FORMAT_\d+$`. What I am doing wrong?

[Fiddle](http://www.regexr.com/3c3or)

Comment: Are you doing it in some specific programming language?

Comment: Whats wrong with the output? Does "SOME_START_FORMAT_" have any special chars in it? Not all regexers are created equal, `\d` and `+` are not standard regexes.

Comment: @Abhishek kumar  - I am trying to use in JavaScript

Comment: @dan08 - No there are character and digit with _ only.

Comment: Your fiddle treats all lines as a single string containing new line characters. Is that what you expect? The regex you posted is fine if the expected input is a single string in the form `SOME_START_FORMAT_1234`.

Comment: I tried your regex in rubular and it's working. http://rubular.com/r/1U2YFfoSin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regex is fine. I think the fiddle is confusing because it treats all of your input as a single String with several new line characters.

Your pattern works as expected on individual Strings:

```js
var input = [
  "SOME_START_FORMAT_1234", 
  "SOME_START_FORMAT_12",
  "SOME_INVALID_FORMAT_1234",
  "SOME_START_FORMAT_",
  "SOME_START_FORMAT_1234_",
  "SOME_START_FORMAT_1234_MORE"
];

var pattern = /^SOME_START_FORMAT_\d+$/;

input.forEach(function(s) {
  var isMatch = s.match(pattern) !== null;
  document.write(s + ": " + isMatch + "<br>")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for end of string instead of end of line so nothing after the digits will match (\z):

```
^SOME_START_FORMAT_\d+\z
```

for multiline this works at [regxr.com](http://regexr.com/3c3p1)

```
/^SOME_START_FORMAT_\d+$/gm
```

just have to add the multiline flag.